# How to generate empty href in an MVC 3 razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For starters, I'm fairly new in MVC3 so my knowledge is limited. I know that what I ask can be achieved by hardcoding plain `<a href="">` in the view page. But is there any way to do that using HTML helper (like ActionLink or RouteLink)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why out of curiosity? If you are generating nothing based on 'real' information from the mvc helpers why not just hard code an href? It seems there's no benefit here to using Html.ActionLink().

Comment: As you said. It's just out of curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create actionlink which has nulls as action and controller parameters and add href = String.Empty in htmlAttributes

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", null, null, new { href = String.Empty })
```

Comment: I suspected it was as simple as that but couldn't wrap my head around it. Didn't thought about using `null`.Thanks a lot.